# Getting wrong contentSize of UITableView in ViewWillAppear

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, autolayout

I am trying to get the contentSize of tableView in viewWillAppear method,but it is coming wrong , when I get the contenSize in ViewDidAppear it is coming correct.  How to get the correct contentSize or why this is happening I am getting the table frame correctly in viewDidLayoutSubView but table contentSize is not corret?

Comment: Getting wrong content size in didlayoutSubView as well.

Comment: This is not duplicate, go to the link and see that question is regarding frame not content offest

Comment: This is releated to contentSize not frame.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in `viewWillAppear` you don't have the right frames of your UI yet. The right frames are in the did appear.

Comment: I want to scroll the table to display the last cell in view will appear. How to do that ??